# Is honeysql RDBMS agnostic?

Tags: clojure, honeysql

I would like to use honeysql https://github.com/jkk/honeysql with MySQL and with SQlite at the same time.

Can I do so? Will resulting queries work in both RDBMS systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the README :

> To quote identifiers, pass the :quoting keyword option  to format. Valid options are :ansi (PostgreSQL), :mysql, or:sqlserver:

So I don't think sqlite is supported